# Terraform Kubernetes provisioner "local-exec" kubectl apply -f -<<EOF on Windows not working

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, terraform, kubectl

I am trying to create/apply this kubectl .yaml file https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/blob/master/deploy/infra/deployment.yaml  via Terrraform`s null_resource to the AKS to install Azure AD Pod Identity. It needed to deploy Azure Gateway Ingress Controller.
Using Windows 10 with VS Code

**main.tf:**

```
data "template_file" "aad_pod" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/aad_pod.yaml")}"
}

resource "null_resource" "aad_pod_deploy" {
  triggers = {
    manifest_sha1 = "${sha1("${data.template_file.aad_pod.rendered}")}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f -<<EOF\n${data.template_file.aad_pod.rendered}\nEOF"
  }
}
```

After terraform apply I have this error:

```
Error: Error running command 'kubectl apply -f -<<EOF
'cutted listing of yaml file'
EOF': exit status 1. Output: << was unexpected at this time.
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don’t know if this is the problem or not, but I always put a space before and after the <<

Comment: unfortunately it does not help :\

Comment: Are you aware that "local-exec" uses "sensible defaults" for the interpreter it uses to run  the command? ( see here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html#interpreter) . When you're on windows, I would doubt that it's executing that in Bash but instead in powershell. So heredocs won't work as far as i'm concerned.

Comment: Why wouldn't you template that out to a file and then use the _normal_ value for the `-f` argument: a file or URL?

Answer (score 7):

Because of differences between Unix-like operating systems and Windows, it's rarely possible to use `local-exec` in a portable way unless your use-case is very simple. This is one of the reasons why [provisioners are a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#provisioners-are-a-last-resort).

I think the most portable answer would be to use [the official Kubernetes provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes) to interact with Kubernetes here. Alternatively, if using `kubectl`'s input format in particular is important for what you are doing, you could use [a community-maintained `kubectl` provider](https://github.com/gavinbunney/terraform-provider-kubectl).

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "example" {
  yaml_body = data.template_file.aad_pod.rendered
}
```

---

If you have a strong reason to use the `local-exec` provisioner rather than a native Terraform provider, you'll need to find a way to write a command that can be interpreted in a compatible way by both a Unix-style shell and by Windows's command line conventions. I expect it would be easier to achieve that by writing the file out to disk first and passing the filename to `kubectl`, because that avoids the need to use any special features of the shell and lets everything be handled by `kubectl` itself:

```
resource "local_file" "aad_pod_deploy" {
  filename = "${path.module}/aad_pod.yaml"
  content  = data.template_file.aad_pod.rendered

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f ${self.filename}"
  }
}
```

There are still some caveats to watch out for with this approach. For example, if you run Terraform under a directory path containing spaces then `self.filename` will contain spaces and therefore probably won't be parsed as you want by the Unix shell or by the `kubectl` Windows executable.

Comment: The Unix/Windows issue is no longer a problem with v0.14.7 :) - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v0.14.7#tag-select-menu-430d5702-75f8-11eb-8f34-f419f9c38f6f:~:text=provisioner%2Fremote%2Dexec%3A%20Can%20now%20run%20in%20a,interpreter%2C%20rather%20than%20a%20Unix%2Dstyle%20shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. I found the solution. I am using helm_release resource in terraform. Just create your helm chart with necessary template and use it with helm_release.
I made a helm chart for AAD Identity and it make the job